# How to keep declined meetings on my calendar?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to keep declined meetings on my calendar.

This code, keeps cancelled meetings:
https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/meeting-cancellation-calendar/

```vb
Sub CopyMeetingtoAppointment(oRequest As MeetingItem)

    If oRequest.MessageClass <> "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Canceled" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
    Dim cAppt As AppointmentItem

    Set cAppt = oRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
    Set oAppt = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    oAppt.Subject = "(Rule) Canceled: " & cAppt.Subject
    oAppt.Start = cAppt.Start
    oAppt.Duration = cAppt.Duration
    oAppt.Location = cAppt.Location
    oAppt.Display
    oAppt.Save

    Set oAppt = Nothing
    Set cAppt = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want my calendar to show declined meetings.

Comment: So what happens when you run that code?

Comment: So i create rule and choose to run this script.  When I get sent a meeting and i decline it my calendar doesn't show the meeting anymore.

Comment: If you display a message box (MsgBox "Test") in CopyMeetingtoAppointment, does it get displayed?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, this is my first time using vba. Can you provide some details how to display a message box?

Answer (score 0):

You must create a rule for handling incoming items with the 'run script' Action and select this script.

Comment: I did do this and when I get sent a meeting and I decline it, its now longer on my calendar.  I did add this registry key; HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security
DWORD: EnableUnsafeClientMailRules
Value: 1